# Launching .bat files on Windows with Adobe AIR NativeProcess, not supported?

Tags: batch-file, air

I can easily start "sh" files on Mac, but when I try the same with bat on Windows I get this:

The NativeProcess could not be started. 'Files with '.bat' extensions cannot be launched.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, [you can't do that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html#start%28%29).

> AIR on Windows does not allow you to run .bat files directly. Windows .bat files are executed by the command interpreter application (cmd.exe). When you invoke a .bat file, this command application can interpret arguments passed to the command as additional applications to launch. A malicious injection of extra characters in the argument string could cause cmd.exe to execute a harmful or insecure application. For example, without proper data validation, your AIR application may call myBat.bat myArguments c:/evil.exe. The command application would launch the evil.exe application in addition to running your batch file.
>
> If you call the start() method with a .bat file, the NativeProcess object throws an exception. The message property of the Error object contains the string "Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started."

Instead, try starting `cmd.exe` with the arguments `/c your-batch-file.bat`.

Comment: what does the argument /c do?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work for me. var f:File = new File("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"); this gives me error that it is not a valid executable file. And this, var f:File = new File("cmd.exe"), that arguments are invalid.

Comment: Stupid me, I forgot to escape backslashes. new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"). This works.

Answer (score 6):

Rename the file from *.bat to *.cmd and it works like a charm.

So much for security.

Answer (score 1):

```
var batUrl:String = "outProtoCmd.bat";
```

var file:File = new File(batUrl);
file.openWithDefaultApplication();